# Org-mode: Automatic fill-paragraph for TODO Closing Note?

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph, todo

In Emacs `org-mode`, I like to use TODO items. I switched on the automatic closing note, when an entry is marked DONE.

A small annoyance is that the fill behavior of the closing note usually changes from the `*Org Note*` buffer, where the message is entered, to the original Org-file. To have the right filling after inserting the closing note, I have to scroll down a few lines and use the `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`).

Is there a possibility to have automatic filling for the closing note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust the value of `fill-column` in the Org note buffer.
If `org-adapt-indentation` is non-nil, this needs to take into account
the heading level.

```
(defvar org-log-current-level nil)
(advice-add 'org-add-log-note :before
            (lambda ()
              (setq org-log-current-level (org-current-level))))

(defun org-log-adjust-fill-column ()
  (let ((offset (if org-adapt-indentation (+ org-log-current-level 3) 2)))
    (setq fill-column (- fill-column offset))))

(add-hook 'org-log-buffer-setup-hook #'org-log-adjust-fill-column)
```

Comment: I just tried to see if this works. Sadly I'm using Emacs 24.3 and the `advice-add` does not exist... Is there an easy way to work around this?

Comment: Ok, I now tried it with an Emacs 24.4, which I do not use for AucTeX compatibility issues, but it works for some first tries, so I mark the answer with the green hook. Thanks!